# how to show/hide metabox, if click on the Specified category

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

How to display or Hide a Specified `< div id="specified-div"></ div>` , when click on the `< input type="checkbox" value="9" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-9" checked="checked" >`

i need to show #specified-div , when input is checked, 
and hide #specified-div , when input is not checked .

if it can helps, i use word-press and needs to hide/show meta-box when click on the categories input checkbox?

Comment: in admin panel or front-end?  Also what code you have tried so for? what is the html structure?

Comment: i edit that, its ok now

Comment: @ShahePars Do you still have problems or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will use the `.prop("checked")` to see if the checkbox is either checked or not

```js
$('#in-category-9').on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $("#specified-div").show()
  } else {
    $("#specified-div").hide()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="specified-div">HIDE OR SHOW</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="9" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-9" checked="checked">
```

Comment: `toggle()` is far better than `hide()` and `show()`

Comment: True, but if the input don't have `checked="checked"` then it does the opposite of what he wanted. That's why i include show and hide and the prop check to give an example of how to also void that